# How to change wcf response type based on parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

my WCF service get request looks like below:

1. ../myservice.svc/search?q=keywords&op=xml
2. ../myservice.svc/search?q=keywords&op=json

so based on param **op**, response type should change. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx) you have complex article about setting response in different formats. If you are using WCF 4 I would definitely think about setting [automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webhttpbehavior.automaticformatselectionenabled.aspx) in `WebHttpBehavior`. It will automatically choose response format (XML or JSON) based on client's HTTP Accept header.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be the `WebGetAttribute` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx

```
public class MyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "search?q={keyword}&op=xml")]
    string GetXml(string keyword);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "search?q={keyword}&op=json")]
    string GetJson(string keyword);
}
```

note: above not tested

Comment: I'm using WebGetAttribute, but do i need to write 2 methods/wrappers for same logic? is it only the solution?

Comment: Another option would be to have a single method, capture `op` as a parameter and format the response on the way out. But that depends on what type(s) you're returning.